# VBoxSVGA vs VMSVGA Resolution Issues on Linux guest

Tags: linux, virtualbox, resolution, vga, display-adapter

I'm trying to install LMDE (Linux Mint Debian Edition) 3 on a Windows 10 host. I'm having some trouble with the graphics adapters and resolution settings. I read [this SU question](https://superuser.com/questions/1403123/what-are-differences-between-vboxvga-vmsvga-and-vboxsvga-in-virtualbox), and specifically Mokubai's answer, which helped me. However, I'm running into some issues that neither the VirtualBox user manual nor Mokubai's answer resolves. I'm still at the stage of running the LMDE Live CD and then trying to run the graphical installer.

So, I initially tried using the VMSVGA adapter because as the [current user manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html#settings-display) seems to indicate, this is the default adapter for Linux guests and (by inference) should be the one to use. However, when using it I could only get a max resolution of 800 x 600, even with trying to use Hint in Global Settings > Display. I did have 3D Acceleration checked and that seemed fine. The problem with the low resolution was that when I ran the installer, on the first screen alone I couldn't see the whole window and no amount of moving or resizing the window helped. As a result, I just couldn't see enough to click on the Next button.

I finally tried using VBoxSVGA and it did let me use a max resolution of 1024 x 768. This resolution let me see the full installer window, allowing me to click on Next. However, when LMDE Live CD starts, I get a message once I get to the desktop screen that "Cinnamon is currently running without hardware acceleration" and instead "running in software rendering mode".

Any ideas on why this might be? Is VBoxSVGA only supposed to be used for Windows 7+ guests, while even modern Linux guests are supposed to use VMSVGA? If so, then how can I get my resolution higher? And if VBoxSVGA can be used for Linux guests, then how do I get hardware acceleration to be enabled?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: This question is NOT a duplicate of a previous question. My question is not simply about differences between VBoxSVA and VMSVGA but specifically resolution issues I'm having with those two graphics adapters on a Linux guest. In my question, I even reference the other question that Mokubai thought mine was a duplicate of. I edited my question title to hopefully show the difference.

Comment: Which VirtualBox version are you running? There were many VMSVGA fixes in 6.0.6.

Comment: I'm using VB 6.0.6 r130049 (Qt5.6.2); I installed VB fresh only a few days ago, which is why I was surprised I was having this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem with the resolution issues. Once I installed LMDE 3 and installed the Guest Additions, VMSVGA seemed to work fine. VBoxSVGA also worked fine in terms of resolution issues, but I still kept getting the software rendering warning.