# how to use NVIDIA card within windows to launch ubuntu VM using Virtual Box

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, nvidia-graphics-card

I cannot launch any virtual machine using NVIDIA card. there is no option that i can do so (even after i open nvidia control pannel and ensure that nvidia card is working and then i select open using NVIDIA card from the [Context Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJjS0.png))

[display driver result after picking nvidia](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoCG9.png)

Comment: Your display result it worthless.  It won't show you what host driver it is using from there regardless of what that might be.  Also, I would suggest checking the 3d box and changing to VBoxSVGA. ***You DO NOT WANT VMSVGA.***

Comment: To answer your question, see [this](https://opensourceconnections.com/blog/2012/10/06/ubuntu-12-04-guest-performance-in-full-screen/) link.  It references this SU link (making it a duplicate).  https://superuser.com/questions/330568/how-can-i-determine-and-set-my-primary-graphics-card

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas so what should i choose? (VBoxVGA, VMSVGA, VBoxsVGA, none)

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas i did try other options but virtual box says (incompatible option, to use 3D acceleration you should pick VMSVGA)

Comment: ?? CRAZY! ?? VMSVGA is for compatability with VMWare as I understand it.  I have several Linux VMs ranging from Ubuntu to CentOS.. all of which are set to VBoxSVGA with the 3d box checked.  I get excellent 3d performance through them.  Was the image you are using brought over from virtual box??

Comment: See this link too:  [What are differences between VBoxVGA, VMSVGA and VBoxSVGA in VirtualBox?](https://superuser.com/questions/1403123/what-are-differences-between-vboxvga-vmsvga-and-vboxsvga-in-virtualbox)